# Why is res undefined in some cases?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I'm working on a ReactJS project and I'm using Axios to connect to my NodeJS backend using express and a MongoDB Database.

I have a button in my render function that when clicked calls the following function:

```
getInfo() {
   Axios.get('http://localhost:9000/getMyData')
      .then(res => console.log(res));
}
```

This works fine, it connects, queries my database and I can see the results in my console. 
BUT
If I try to set the state with this result, it is undefined.
For example:

```
getInfo() {
   Axios.get('http://localhost:9000/getMyData')
      .then(res => this.setState({data: res})); // or res.data based on the way I want to save it
}
```

I get a 304 response instead of a 200 response, and React says that res is undefined.

I do not understand what is going on here, why can I console log the response, but I can't store it. 
 Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong, and how I can store the data?

Thank you.

Comment: Based on the code you've shown, there's no reason that the second version shouldn't work. Likely, the problem is in some code you haven't shown. Can you provide a [mcve]? Thanks!

Comment: I've sort of figured out what the issue is, just not sure how to solve it. It seems that if I try to access it too 'quickly', it is undefined. But if I set the state as I've done in my sample code, then render a button that calls a separate function to display the data, then it works. Is there a way to wait for a '.then' statement or something like that?

Comment: `axios.get()` returns a promise which you're correctly waiting for resolution with `then`. So, there's no race condition in the code you've shown. If you look at axios' [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios), the first example is "performing a get request" and it looks basically identical to your code. It's not a reproducible example. Likely, there is some other problem with the component state that's misusing the data, or a problem with the backend route. Impossible to say.